# bluetooth InputStream in android gets corrupted after sending with OutputStream

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream, outputstream

So, I am using my arduino to collect some data and send it to my android app , so that I can store this data in a file, making my android a sort of datalogger.
I am using an hC-06 for this, working at 115200 bauds/sec. Seems to be allright when the arduino sends the data chunks ( 60bytes every chunk) every 100ms aprox.
The problem begins when I "query" the arduino for some special data, by sending a single byte with the OutputStream method. From the moment the app uses the "mmOutStream.write(buffer);" the data received by InputStream becomes unstable, varying the chunk size with random values ( 60 bytes, 45 butes, 100 bytes, etc...)
It seems like using OutputStream kind of corrupts the InputStream buffer...
Anyone has been through this? Thaks in advance
below the code:

```
    // It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private boolean send_request=false;
        private byte[] send_buffer;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer;
            ArrayList<Integer> arr_byte = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {

                   try {
                        int data = mmInStream.read();
                        if(data == 0x0A) {

                        }
                        else if(data == 0x0D) {

                            buffer = new byte[arr_byte.size()];
                            for(int i = 0 ; i < arr_byte.size() ; i++) {
                                buffer[i] = arr_byte.get(i).byteValue();
                            }
                            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                            mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothState.MESSAGE_READ
                                    , buffer.length, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                            arr_byte = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        }
                        else {
                            arr_byte.add(data);
                         }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        connectionLost();
                        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                        BluetoothService.this.start(BluetoothService.this.isAndroid);
                        break;
                    }


            }
        }

        // Write to the connected OutStream.
        // @param buffer  The bytes to write
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
           try {

               mmOutStream.write(buffer);

             //  mmOutStream.close();  //vdv , close after writing to see if liberates memeory . uncommenting this causes the phone not to connect
            //TODO: investigate and solve why a single writing in the outstream causes the inputstream to get corrupted after a while.
                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothState.MESSAGE_WRITE
                        ,  -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();

            } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.d(TAG,"write exception");   //vdv
           }

        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to read lines? Then why dont you use the function .readLine()? Lines of 60 chars?

Comment: Hey, yes I am tryin to read lines, as the data frame sent by the arduino is like: XXXXX...XXXX\r\n. this chunk is sent at once. I made sure that none of the X bytes are neither \r nor \n. And the arduino is just sending fine, as I checked it with the osciloscope. Where is the method .readline? coudnt find it in InputStream class

Comment: .readLine() is in DataInputStream or BufferedInputStream or InputStreamReader or such. I forgot. Plenty examples on stackoverflow.

Comment: Using TCP dont expect that evey chunck send comes in as that chunck. The amount of bytes that come in everytime may vary. You have to concatenate if needed. But readLine() does a lot for you as you always will get a line. Or null.

Comment: ok Thanks, I will try to rewrite the code to use this method . readline().  But what really puzzles me is that bluetooth connection in my phone is working great, receiving data and storing it, until the moment the moment I send one single byte from my phone to the hc06 antenna, then everythig start to crumble. ..